# Agrandar la imagen de un ImageView dentro de un Layout en Android

Tags: android, layout, picasso

Descargo mediante Picasso una imagen de internet y cargo el resultado en un ImageView que se encuentra dentro de un Layout. El problema al que me enfrento es que la imagen no ocupa todo el tamaño del Layout y se me queda acoplada en un lateral y pequeña.

[image: Situación]

Código Java:

```
ImageView graph = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.graphImageView);
Picasso.with(this).load("https://www.google.com/finance/getchart?q=INTC&p=20Y&i=86400").into(graph);
```

XML:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/graphLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="343dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/activityStockLinearLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/graphImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Puede que se me escape algún parámetro en el XML que hace referencia al ImageView y que logre hacer que ocupe todo el tamaño de dentro del marco que el Layout proporciona al ImageView. He tratado de cambiar el parámetro **wrap_content** por **match_parent** Pero no logro hacerlo....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Si tu contenedor tiene definido `343dp` de alto, los elementos contenidos solo se pueden desplegar en esta área, esta es la razón por la cual tu imagen no se ve más grande**, considera cambiar el alto de tu `LinearLayout` a una medida más grande o definir :

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

y obviamente tu `ImageView` tendría las propiedades:

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Comment: solucione el problema pero tuve que poner un height fijo sino en layout de abajo se agrandaba demasiado. Gracias ;D

Comment: Es lo que comento en la respuesta el ImagView va a crecer el tamaño que le permita su contenedor.

Answer (score 0):

Al final solucione el problema dejando de esta manera el XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/graphLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="353dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/activityStockLinearLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/graphImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```